# How can I restore a bacpac file from Azure storage to an Azure SQL Server as the database?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sql-database, azure-cli

I have a `.bacpac` file in Azure storage and want to restore it as the database on an Azure SQL Server. The `.bacpac` file is called `testdb`.

I am using the following command:

```
az sql db import --admin-password <sql_server_admin_password> --admin-user <sql_server_admin_username>
   --storage-key <storage_account_key> --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey 
   --storage-uri <bacpac_file_uri> --name 'newtestdb'
   --resource-group 'testrg' --server 'testserver'
```

The issue is that it says `servers/testserver/databases/newtestdb`  under resource group `testrg` was not found.

I thought it creates the new database on that server under the resource group `testrg`.

How can I restore the `.bacpac` file to a SQL Server in a resource group?

Comment: you need to create the db first: `az sql db create`

Comment: `az sql db import` imports to an existing db as per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-import

Comment: so your saying that if the name in storage is "testdbstoragesave" I need to create a db on the server first lets say called "testdbrestore" and then do the import ?

Comment: I thought it would just create a db with the name of the bacpac file ?

Comment: the command expects the db to be created first. so create the db then import :-)

Comment: ok so i need to create a server , create a db and then do the restore via az cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the bacpac uploaded to an Azure Storage account, you need to create first the resource group, then Azure SQL logical server, then create an empty Azure SQL database on that logical server, finally import the database with the name of the newly created database. Below a fully functional script of AZ commands and the order you need to execute them:

```
# Import a BACPAC file into a database in SQL Database

let "randomIdentifier=$RANDOM*$RANDOM"
location="East US"
resourceGroup="msdocs-azuresql-rg-$randomIdentifier"
tag="import-from-bacpac"
server="msdocs-azuresql-server-$randomIdentifier"
database="msdocsazuresqldb$randomIdentifier"
login="azureuser"
password="Pa$$w0rD-$randomIdentifier"
storage="msdocsazuresql$randomIdentifier"
container="msdocs-azuresql-container-$randomIdentifier"
bacpac="sample.bacpac"

echo "Using resource group $resourceGroup with login: $login, password: $password..."

echo "Creating $resourceGroup in $location..."
az group create --name $resourceGroup --location "$location" --tags $tag

echo "Creating $storage..."
az storage account create --name $storage --resource-group $resourceGroup --location "$location" --sku Standard_LRS

echo "Creating $container on $storage..."
key=$(az storage account keys list --account-name $storage --resource-group $resourceGroup -o json --query [0].value | tr -d '"')

az storage container create --name $container --account-key $key --account-name $storage #--public-access container

echo "Downloading sample database..."
az rest --uri https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/download/wide-world-importers-v1.0/WideWorldImporters-Standard.bacpac --output-file $bacpac -m get --skip-authorization-header

echo "Uploading sample database to $container..."
az storage blob upload --container-name $container --file $bacpac --name $bacpac --account-key $key --account-name $storage

echo "Creating $server in $location..."
az sql server create --name $server --resource-group $resourceGroup --location "$location" --admin-user $login --admin-password $password
az sql server firewall-rule create --resource-group $resourceGroup --server $server --name AllowAzureServices --start-ip-address 0.0.0.0 --end-ip-address 0.0.0.0

echo "Creating $database..."
az sql db create --name $database --resource-group $resourceGroup --server $server --edition "GeneralPurpose"

echo "Importing sample database from $container to $database..."
az sql db import --admin-password $password --admin-user $login --storage-key $key --storage-key-type StorageAccessKey --storage-uri https://$storage.blob.core.windows.net/$container/$bacpac --name $database --resource-group $resourceGroup --server $server
```